# Maven doesn´t check JUnit tests

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I configured Maven with Junit using mainly this tutorial:
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html

I have a one test Class and when I execute "mvn test", this test Class is caught by Maven but Maven doesn´t check it (The result should be FAIL).

```
C:\Users\User\git\example\example>mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building passport 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ passport -
--
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ passport ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ pa
ssport ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ passpor
t ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ passport ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.472 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-22T12:07:27+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My Test Class is in src/main/resources (the console shows "Copying 1 resource"):

```
package main.resources;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class exampleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        int result = 5;
        assertTrue(result == 2);    
    }
}
```

My POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>passport</name>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Maven version:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-13T21:10:2
7+01:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Any idea why don´t check the test Case?

Other question, I don´t know because shows a warning about enconding CP1252 when I have configured my project with UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question the [following should be made part of your pom](https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning):

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your test class must reside in `src/test/java` and **NOT** in `src/main/resources` Take a look at the [default folder layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution, I keep your link for default folder layout.

I mark this post with "resolved" because the mainly question is resolved but I have still the doubt about the encoding cp1252.

Comment: See my supplemental answer.